# Views filter: how to compare two fields?

Tags: 7, entities, views

I have two content types "type1" and "type2" and one taxonomy. I have assigned the taxonomy to both of the content types. In type1 its name is "field_type1_test" and in type its name is "field_type2_test".

Now I want to fetch the title and body from the "type1" Where values of "field_type1_test" = "field_type2_test".

Is this possible?

If yes then how will I do this in views? Help please.

Comment: Yessss, I want this too! =(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure **you** are going to use it, but for those who may get here looking for the same:

Under the `Filter Criteria`, Search for `"Globals: Fields Comparison"`.
For the record, the fields you want to compare should be among the fields you are loading in the current View.

So, if you want to compare to something you are not willing to show, you should add the fields to the View and check the `Exclude from display`.

Hope it helps!